# `phpize' failed, while installing Imagick

Tags: php, imagick, intervention

First i run *brew install imagemagick* and then *pecl install imagick*

```
Shahbazs-MBP:~ shahbazmancho$ sudo pecl install imagick
Password:
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading imagick-3.4.4.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.4.4.tgz (253,434 bytes)
.....................................................done: 253,434 bytes
19 source files, building
running: phpize
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

And my php version is

```
PHP 7.3.9 (cli) (built: Sep 10 2019 17:45:01) ( NTS )
```

Comment: Probably need `sudo apt install php-dev`